# Looking for info on BIOS options

Tags: bios, dell-xps

Where can I find documentation on the options in my BIOS?  I haven't been able to find anything.

My computer is a Dell XPS 15 L501X laptop, BIOS is Phoenix A07.

Comment: Are you looking for a manual, or just help with specific settings?

Comment: normal thing is just google the setting if it isn't self explanatory. phoenix bios is fairly standard. and you can try to change a setting and see what happens and if it's no good for you then just change it back.

Comment: Your OS doesn't mean anything. I'm going to take it out because it is extraneous information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find anything like a manual for that specific model's BIOS, or the BIOS itself. That it probably because they usually rely on the built-in help files, scant as they may be.

There was nothing in this model's manuals regarding the BIOS:

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/xpsl501x/en/index.htm

I found this general link regarding the Phoenix BIOS. It may not have every setting yours has, but should help:

http://www.computerhope.com/help/phoenix.htm

I also found this specific information about another Dell model (not sure why they don't do this for all models):

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/psyd/setup.htm

Comment: Thank you too for marking it. I hope it helped you get most of what you were looking for.